# Как записать данные пользователя в лог файл в SpringSecurity

Tags: spring-security

Всем добрый день. Интересует вопрос как записать данные пользователя в log - файл при его входе в MVC приложение, к которому подключен SpringSecurity. 
Для странички регистрации я записываю данные пользователя следующим образом:
в контролере странички я создаю логер и методе saveUser записываю информацию о пользователе в лог файл следующим образом.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public class RegistrationController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RegistrationController.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    CityService cityService;

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    RoleService roleService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String renderRegistration(ModelMap model) {
        Persons person = new Persons();

        model.addAttribute("userForm", person);
        model.addAttribute("edit", false);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "registration";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userForm") Persons person, BindingResult result,
                           ModelMap model) {

        List<FieldError> errors = new ArrayList<>();

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "errorPage";
        }

        if (person.getNickname().isEmpty()) {
            FieldError nicknameError = new FieldError("person", "nickname", messageSource.getMessage("NotEmpty.person.nickname", new String[]{person.getNickname()}, Locale.getDefault()));
            errors.add(nicknameError);
        }

        if (!personService.isPersonsNicknameUnique(person.getPersonId(), person.getNickname())) {
            FieldError nicknameUniqError = new FieldError("person", "nickname", messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.nickname", new String[]{person.getNickname()}, Locale.getDefault()));
            errors.add(nicknameUniqError);
        }


        if (person.getPassword().isEmpty()) {
            FieldError passwordError = new FieldError("person", "password", messageSource.getMessage("NotEmpty.person.password", new String[]{person.getNickname()}, Locale.getDefault()));
            errors.add(passwordError);
        }

        if (person.getFirstName().isEmpty()) {
            FieldError firstNameError = new FieldError("person", "firstName", messageSource.getMessage("NotEmpty.person.firstName", new String[]{person.getNickname()}, Locale.getDefault()));
            errors.add(firstNameError);
        }

        if (person.getLastName().isEmpty()) {
            FieldError lastNameError = new FieldError("person", "lastName", messageSource.getMessage("NotEmpty.person.lastName", new String[]{person.getNickname()}, Locale.getDefault()));
            errors.add(lastNameError);
        }

        if (person.getEmail().isEmpty()) {
            FieldError emailError = new FieldError("person", "email", messageSource.getMessage("NotEmpty.person.email", new String[]{person.getNickname()}, Locale.getDefault()));
            errors.add(emailError);
        }

        if (person.getCity().equals(null)) {
            FieldError cityError = new FieldError("person", "city", messageSource.getMessage("NotEmpty.person.city", new String[]{person.getNickname()}, Locale.getDefault()));
            errors.add(cityError);
        }
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {

            for (FieldError error : errors) {
                result.addError(error);
            }
            return "registration";
        }
//        person.setRole(roleService.findByType("USER"));
        personService.savePerson(person);

        if (Const.DEBUG) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("person: id-" + person.getPersonId() +
                        " Nickname-" + person.getNickname() +
                        " Password-" + person.getPassword() +
                        " Lastname-" + person.getLastName() +
                        " FirstName-" + person.getFirstName() +
                        " Email-" + person.getEmail() +
                        " City-" + person.getCity().getCityName() +
                        " MobileNumber-" + person.getMobileNumber());
            }
        }

        return "success";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("rollers")
    public List<Rollers> getRollers() { return roleService.findAll();}

    @ModelAttribute("cities")
    public List<Cities> initializeCities() {
        return cityService.getAll();
    }

    private String getPrincipal() {
        String userName = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            userName = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            userName = principal.toString();
        }
        return userName;
    }
}
```

Аналогичную операцию мне надо сделать при входе пользователя, но так как у меня подключен SpringSecurity, то он обрабатывает метод POST, в итоге я не пойму как мне записать данные пользователя в файл.
PS: за код не ругайте, я знаю он не очень)

Пытался сделать так:

```
   @Component
public class CustomSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomSuccessHandler.class.getName());

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException {
        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);

        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            System.out.println("Can't redirect");
            return;
        }

//        String userName;
//        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
//        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
//            userName = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
//        } else {
//            userName = principal.toString();
//        }
//        if (Const.DEBUG) {
//            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("person: Nickname-" + authentication.getPrincipal().toString());
                logger.debug("person: Nickname-");
//            }
//        }

        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

    /*
     * This method extracts the roles of currently logged-in user and returns
     * appropriate URL according to his/her role.
     */
    protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
        String url = "";

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();

        // для одной роли
        GrantedAuthority auth = authorities.iterator().next();
        String role = auth.getAuthority();


        // для нескольких ролей
//        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
//        for (GrantedAuthority a : authorities) {
//            roles.add(a.getAuthority());
//        }

        switch (role) {
            case "ROLE_USER":
                url = "/user";
                break;
            case "ROLE_DRIVER":
                url = "/driver";
                break;
            case "ROLE_OWNER":
                url = "/owner";
                break;
            case "ROLE_ADMIN":
                url = "/admin";
                break;
            default:
                url = "/accessDenied";
        }
        return url;
    }



    public void setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy) {
        this.redirectStrategy = redirectStrategy;
    }

    protected RedirectStrategy getRedirectStrategy() {
        return redirectStrategy;
    }
}
```

в SecurityConfiguration:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

//
//    @Autowired
//    LoginSuccess loginSuccess;

    @Autowired
    CustomSuccessHandler customSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/driver/**").hasRole("DRIVER")
                .antMatchers("/owner/**").hasRole("OWNER")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(customSuccessHandler)
//                .successHandler(loginSuccess)
                .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
                .and().csrf()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
//        http.addFilterAfter(new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTrustResolver getAuthenticationTrustResolver() {
        return new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
    }


}
```

тоже не помогло. Также пытался через onAuthenticationSuccess - тоже не получилось.

Настройки log4j:

```
    log4j.logger.com.team.mvc.configuration.CustomSuccessHandler=INFO, CustomSuccessHandler
log4j.additivity.com.team.mvc.configuration.CustomSuccessHandler=false
log4j.appender.CustomSuccessHandler=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CustomSuccessHandler.File=E:\\LoginSuccess.out
log4j.appender.CustomSuccessHandler.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CustomSuccessHandler.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} %C:%M:%L - %m%n
```

Причем когда пробовал через фильтр - не мог получить security контекст, и метод getPrincipal бросал NullPointException. В данный раз исключений нет, но в лог тоже ничего не пишется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте **AuthenticationSuccessHandler**

```
@Component
public class LoginSuccess implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println(authentication.getPrincipal());
    }
}
```

И подключите его в конфигурации **SpringSecurity**. Если нужно узнавать о неудачных попытка входа, то создайте **AuthenticationFailureHandler**.

Comment: Вопрос: как он работает? Он сработает после входа или перед входом? Я пытаюсь с помощью фильтра сделать, пока без результатов.

Comment: после удачного входа будет вызван метод `onAuthenticationSuccess`

Comment: Спасибо, за пример